# How to detect browser type with Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Inside a Cloud Function,
I would like to serve different pages for mobile and desktop.
I would like to know :

1. if its mobile or desktop (or a good guess) that want this page
2. If possible to get the browser/Google default language

The goal is to serve different users with different urls.

```
     exports.contentServer = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

     //determine here if its mobile or not
```

Comment: Browser capability detection is typically something you want to do in the browser itself, not in code running on a backend.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks, but it means that user ask for domain.com, then he get a redirect page back, where i figure this out, then ask server again for the right version of the page (mobile/desktop), right ? this takes double the time to load .

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "takes double the time".  The client is making all the decisions based on its capabilities.  How does that double anything?

Comment: @DougStevenson have you read the rest of my comment other than the conclusion? its there. you access the server twice instead of once.

Comment: I read the whole thing. Maybe you could edit the question to be more explain the specific, measurable problem you're trying to avoid by detecting the browser capabilities in the browser itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following npm package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-browser

Install it by executing in the terminal:

```
npm i detect-browser
```

Then you can do for example:

```
const { detect } = require('detect-browser');
const browser = detect();

// handle the case where we don't detect the browser
if (browser) {
  console.log(browser.name);
  console.log(browser.version);
  console.log(browser.os);
}
```

Comment: Hey Peter. Are you sure the browser detection works? I thought that headers were dropped before the request reaches the Cloud Functions code.

Comment: there seems to be a problem, is there any simple/native way to know if its mobile or not ?

Comment: @phamng why dnt u handle browser type on the front end, in cloud functions retrieve the data and in front end handle the type

Comment: @PeterHaddad thanks, because it means more time on load: user typed domain.com, go to my function, get some redirect page, i figure out if its mobile or not, go again to the server and ask for domainMobile/Desktop. Is that what you mean ? sounds not effecient(?)